# How to rename file using express-formidable package

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

Can't figure out on how to rename the file using the express [formidable package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable)

server.js contents:

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()
const formidableMiddleware = require('express-formidable')

app.use(formidableMiddleware({
  uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/files',
  multiples: true,
  keepExtensions: true
}))

router.route('/send/:mail')
  .post((req, res) => {
    let file = null
    if (req.files) {
      file = fs.readFileSync(req.files.file.path)
    }
    // here's the code to send email with mailgun js wrapper
  })
```

Purpose of my code is to rename uploaded file, then send it as attachment via mailgun wrapper, however i'm stuck at the step of renaming the file using `fs.rename()` - i just don't know where to put it. Do i need to use `node-formidable` package together with `express-formidable`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `fs.renameSync`:

```
fs.renameSync(req.files['files[0]'], req.files['files[0]'].name)
```